# Magento 2 - First Module - AJAX

Tags: magento2, module, ajax

I'm creating my first module which has been going well, I've managed to create the controller, block and route and can access the page.

I'm now trying to perform an ajax query and return some product data but this is where I'm now struggiling, I've got the following files:

```
<?php

namespace MoudleName\ProductSelector\Controller\Ajax;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct($context, $resultJsonFactory, $productCollectionFactory) {

        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products

        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax())
        {
            return $result->setData($collection);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Ajax query:

```
$('.ajax-query').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/productselector/ajax/index",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But I just get a 500 error and in the logs I'm getting the following error:

```
3382#3382: *5889 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function ModuleName\ProductSelector\Controller\Ajax\Index::__construct(), 2 passed in /var/www/generated/code/ModuleName/ProductSelector/Controller/Ajax/index/Interceptor.php on line 14 and exactly 3 expected in /var/www/app/code/ModuleName/ProductSelector/Controller/Ajax/index.php:14
```

If anyone can shed any light on this it'd be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your controller code like this.

```
<?php

namespace MoudleName\ProductSelector\Controller\Ajax;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory, CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory) {

        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$resultJsonFactory,$productCollectionFactory);

    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products

        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax())
        {
            return $result->setData($collection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Confirm after above changes, remove generated folder and run the commands again and then check.

Comment: I've made that change, now I get this error: 3382#3382: *5894 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ModuleName\ProductSelector\Controller\Ajax\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context given, called in /var/www/generated/code/ModuleName/ProductSelector/Controller/Ajax/index/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/app/code/FirstInternet/ProductSelector/Controller/Ajax/index.php:14

Comment: I edit the answer, kindly check that one. you use wrong contect object into the controller. I now make it correct. \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

Comment: Thanks Dhiren, I seem to be back to the old error again now.

3382#3382: *5898 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function FirstInternet\ProductSelector\Controller\Ajax\Index::__construct(), 2 passed in /var/www/generated/code/ModuleName/ProductSelector/Controller/Ajax/index/Interceptor.php on line 14 and exactly 3 expected in /var/www/app/code/ModuleName/ProductSelector/Controller/Ajax/index.php:14

Comment: try to change this line parent::__construct($context); like this one.
parent::__construct($context,$resultJsonFactory,$productCollectionFactory);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95219/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-webdevb).

Comment: Thanks @Dhiren Vasoya